# SQL query that considers data from other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables:

`employees`:

`id, CMS_user_id, practice_group_id, ...`

and

`users`:

`id, level, ...`

I want to select all employees where `practice_group_id` is 2 but only if the respective user has a `level` of 1 according to the `users` table. I researched and I have a feeling it has something to do with the `UNION` keyword eventually, but I can't quite figure it out.

In "human language", the query would be like this:
"select all from `employees` where `practice_group_id` is 2 and then check the `CMS_user_id` from the employee and check in the table `users` whether the respective user with the `id` that equals `CMS_user_id` has a `level` of 1"

Comment: hwat does it mean checkupt what os your wanted output

Comment: Thank you Allen, I thought I was clear, but apparently I need to formulate my questions more clear next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `JOIN` will match the corresponding rows between two tables. Then, filtering can be done using `WHERE`.

For example:

```
select e.*
from employees e
join users u on u.id = e.CMS_user_id
where e.practice_group = 2 and u.level = 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much, works! I need to read about `JOIN` now